# Sequelize "Error: Invalid value" on simple query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I was able to create a user using sequelize; however, I get a `Invalid value` error when I query any user.

Sequelize User model:

```
import DataTypes from "sequelize";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import config from "../../config.js";

export default (sequelize) => {
  sequelize.define("user", {
    id: {
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(25),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(60),
      allowNull: false,
      set(value) {
        this.setDataValue(
          "password",
          bcrypt.hashSync(value, config.saltRounds)
        );
      },
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
  });
};
```

Query:

```
import { sequelize as db } from "./database/index.js";
import Op from "sequelize";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import config from "./config.js";

const hashedPwd = bcrypt.hashSync("pass", config.saltRounds);

db.models.user
  .findOne({
    where: {
      [Op.and]: [{ username: "user" }, { password: hashedPwd }],
    },
  })
  .then((user) => {
    console.log(user);
    console.log(user.id)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

DB entry:

[image]

Result:

```
> node .\test.js
Error: Invalid value { username: 'user' }
    at Object.escape (node_modules\sequelize\lib\sql-string.js:65:11)
    at MariaDBQueryGenerator.escape (node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:995:22)
    at node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2572:69
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MariaDBQueryGenerator._whereParseSingleValueObject (node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2572:52)
    at MariaDBQueryGenerator.whereItemQuery (node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2354:19)
    at node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2259:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at MariaDBQueryGenerator.whereItemsQuery (node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2257:35)
    at MariaDBQueryGenerator.getWhereConditions (node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2675:19)
```

Why does any username I query result in a `Invalid value` error?

Comment: What version of sequelize did you use?

Comment: 6.9.0, the latest. @slideshowp2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try importing `Op` like this. It [is not](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/f58154334d98038deafbecd017cf5719d1b13b7f/lib/sequelize.js#L1277) a `default` export.

```js
import { Op } from 'sequelize';
```

Secondly, top-level `Op.and` can be replaced with

```js
db.models.user
  .findOne({
    where: {
      username: 'user',
      password: hashedPwd,
    },
  })
```

And lastly (not related to this question at all), `bcrypt` will return a different string each time for the `hash`(sync/async) call. This means that your `where` condition will always fail to find something. So I'd recommend finding a user by username/email and then checking the password by the

```js
db.models.user.findOne({ where: { username: 'myUsername' } })
  .then((user) => {
    return bcrypt.compareSync('myPassword', user.password)
  })
  .then((isMatch) => {
    if (!isMatch) {
      throw new Error('UNAUTHORIZED') // or whatever
    }
  })
```

Comment: I had same issue ,, instead of importing Op from sequelize ,, I imported Sequelize and used Op like this,,, **Sequelize.Op.or**

Answer (score 0):

First, Op should be imported from sequelize as

```
import { Op } from 'sequelize';
```

Then you can query the user just by using the unique field (email/phone_number) like

```
db.models.user.findOne({
 where: {username: "username"}
})
```

this will give you the user, if exists. then you need to compare their password using bcrypt, since bcrypt will be returning different strings each time.

Answer (score 0):

For others experiencing this issue, make sure you aren't putting things in the wrong place. For example, an Include should not be in the Where, but a sibling to it.